# Why Can't I Browse Directly to File Paths of Magento's Downloadable Products?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have a client whose downloadable Magento products are videos that need to be both available for download, and be playable from the "My Account" area. I have everything set up correctly, but the Flash video player cannot access the files via the direct path, even though permissions are set to 777 for all of the files in the `/media/downloadable/files/links/*` area.

I realize that this is intentional on Magento's part as a security issue, but how can I override it? I didn't see anything in the **.htaccess** file that indicated that file permissions were being restricted, but perhaps I missed it somewhere.

Comment: I should add that browsing directly to the downloadable files results in a 403 error.

Comment: You can make downloadable products not expire for people who purchase them. Maybe work that into what you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct access to the downloadable files is blocked in `media/downloadable/.htaccess` :

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that .htaccess file. Thanks a million!